# Xamarin Form not able to invoke the Http URL

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin Cross-Flatform technology (C#). I am developing one small application where I need to call the http url, get the json data, parse it and display it on the screen.

I am using System.Net.Http for achieving the http call.But request is not reaching to http url

Regards,
Amit Joshi

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [RestSharp](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp/) for making http calls.

It is very easy to use.

Code sample:

```
using RestSharp;

var client = new RestClient ("http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/RxTerms/rxcui/");

var request = new RestRequest (String.Format ("{0}/allinfo", "198440"));
client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine (response.Content);
});
```

[RestSharp Examples](http://restsharp.org/)